# Count distinct values in Excel with multiple criteria (strings)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with a large table with 3 main columns (Forward, Reverse and Species).
I need to count distinct species for each pair from Forward and Reverse columns but I can't seem to make it work.
I've tried going around it but the closest thing I found was this: "=SUM(IF(("Jennifer"=$D$6:$D$27)*($B$6:$B$27<=DATE(2011, 1, 31)), 1/COUNTIFS($D$6:$D$27, "Jennifer", $E$6:$E$27, $E$6:$E$27, $B$6:$B$27, "<="&DATE(2011, 1, 31))), 0))", which comes from this website https://www.get-digital-help.com/count-unique-distinct-values-that-meet-multiple-criteria-in-excel/ . Still, it doesn't work when I apply it to my sheet.
I'm a complete newbe with excel so I'm looking for some help please.
I'll drop a print of the sheet as well.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: I would look to replace the SUM() and IF() with SUMIFS() and that would likely help the structure, as it is I don't follow it.

Comment: @SolarMike It is still giveing me 0 after applying SUMIFS(). I'm probably doing it wrong since I don't know how to implement a distinct value count on a sumifs() correctly.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Also returns a 0 regardless of the range.

Thank you both for trying though. I've been smashing my head for a while because of this.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I'm sorry, I don't have an outlook account.
The expected output is the sum of distinct Species that match both my forward and reverse primers on the green table. For example, for "1.2" and "b7.0": 25 (distinct species) and so on for the rest of the table.
I'm sorry if I'm not being clear enough.

Comment: @Weedosaurus so see i have used only 27 rows of data, say me on that respect, becasue that what i can see from the image

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya The problem is not the range. In that range (2:27) the expected output is 2, since 1.2 and b7.0 match with both Eurydice pulchra and Porcellium conspersum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is the formula, you need to use to get the **Sum of Distinct Species**

Formula used in cell **I21**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(($A$2:$A$27=$H21)*($B$2:$B$27=I$20),
1/COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$27,$D$2:$D$27,$A$2:$A$27,$A$2:$A$27,
$B$2:$B$27,$B$2:$B$27),0))
```

And Fill Down!

[image: FORMULA]

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to set this as answer, but in my case it still returns 0, I don't know why. I see it is working as intended on your end though, so it must be another problem for me.

Comment: @Weedosaurus Sir, glad it worked for you, thank you very much!

Comment: @Weedosaurus Sir, once you enter the formula, confirm press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`

Comment: Yes. I'm a total noob and just figured it out now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Weedosaurus yep, i said it will work, since you are using `Excel 2010` you need to press it, its an array formula! Thank you very much again!